# Ignoring error in R function - try() function doesn't work

Tags: r, error-handling

I have a DataFrame with various UTM sources/mediums and I want to segmentize it, so for example for rows with UTM_source = 123 and UTM_medium = ABC/BCD I want to assign name "123ABC". I have over 50 lines like this with many combinations of various sources and mediums ending with "Other" for all other combinations.

The problem is that when I want to assign the value to a non-existent combination the error occurs and breaks the function. To make the code work I have to manually go through all of the 50+ combinations and then run the rest of the code.

```
segment_my_DF <- function(DF) {

  DF$segment <- NA

  # segment based on source and medium  

  DF[!is.na(DF$UTMSource__c) & !is.na(DF$UTMMedium__c) & 
DF$UTMSource__c =="123" & DF$UTMMedium__c =="ABC", ]$segment = 
"123ABC"
  DF[!is.na(DF$UTMSource__c) & !is.na(DF$UTMMedium__c) & 
DF$UTMSource__c =="123" & DF$UTMMedium__c =="BCD", ]$segment = 
"123ABC"
  DF[!is.na(DF$UTMSource__c) & !is.na(DF$UTMMedium__c) & 
DF$UTMSource__c =="234" & DF$UTMMedium__c =="ABC", 
]$segment = "234ABC"
...
  # pack all the others
  DF[is.na(DF$segment), ]$segment = "OTHERS"

  return(DF)
}
```

Let's say the DataFrame I have doesn't have any rows with UTM_Source = '123' and UTM_Medium = 'ABC'. The error message I receive is:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "segment", value = "B2B") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

I'd expect the function just to go further, like an "if" statement. I tried using try() inside the function (both with () and {} brackets):

```
segment_my_DF <- function(DF) {

DF$segment <- NA

  # segment based on source and medium  

try(
...
)

# pack all the others
  DF[is.na(DF$segment), ]$segment = "OTHERS"

  return(DF)
}
```

It makes the function crash immediately. I tried using try() at the moment of calling the function (both with () and {} brackets):

```
segmented_Marketing <- try({segment_my_DF(Rest)})
```

It doesn't work as well. How should I handle this problem? One thing that comes to my mind is to wrap all those 50+ conditions in 50+ "if" statements, but there has to be an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a simple function to do it.  For example,

```
setIfAny <- function(condition, value) {
  if (any(condition))
    DF[condition, "segment"] <<- value
}
```

Because I used the `<<-` superassignment operator, the assignment happens outside the function, and you can do things like

```
setIfAny(!is.na(DF$UTMSource__c) & !is.na(DF$UTMMedium__c) & 
         DF$UTMSource__c =="123" & DF$UTMMedium__c =="ABC", 
         "123ABC")
```

If you want to avoid superassignment, you could pass `DF` into the function and return it at the end:

```
modifyIfAny <- function(data, condition, value) {
   if (any(condition))
      data[condition, "segment"] <- value
   data
}
```

which you would use as

```
DF <- modifyIfAny(DF, 
               !is.na(DF$UTMSource__c) & !is.na(DF$UTMMedium__c) & DF$UTMSource__c =="123" & DF$UTMMedium__c =="ABC", 
               "123ABC")
```